# EXISTS(select 1 from t1) vs EXISTS(select * from t1)

Tags: t-sql

What is the difference between

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from t1)
```

and

```
IF EXISTS(select * from t1)
```

Is the first one more performant than the second?

Comment: For all versions of SQL Server since 2000 these should evaluate the same, except you are referencing two diff. tables here.

Comment: Fixed the table names. Thanks.

Comment: As @JNK says - they're the same.

Comment: No difference at all and you can acid test that by checking both query plan generated